# Not adding calendars and watchman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have to add the library to the project first came to fix it was to erase the cache error, but now says it did not register
Thank you for guiding me.

Here is index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('talar', () => App);
```

[image: http://uupload.ir/files/y4k2_error3.jpg]

---

I've solved this problem now, but the calendar and watchman library does not add what the problem is

http://uupload.ir/files/r7uu_1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you init your projet with `react-native init newProject` for example?

Because if so, you have to match with this name when you do the registerComponent. So it would be

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('newProject', () => App);
```

instead.

EDIT:

According to your screenshot, you should put `AppRegistry.registerComponent('talar', () => App);`

Comment: yes,I changed it myself now because I did not give you a word for you .Now how can i solve this problem without considering this change? @GauthierG

Comment: You mean if you want to keep 'newApp' for this project instead of putting 'talar' in the registerComponent ?

Comment: Thank you, this problem is solved but it does not add any libraries. I've made a change in the question. Please ask me again and if you can help me

Comment: Please open a new question for this (for watchman you should probably close your terminal and open a new one to have it accessible)

Comment: Yes, but I've been limited for a few days
I had to ask here

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => App);
```

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the project name which u have initiated doesn't appear in the **AppRegistry**

> AppRegistry.registerComponent('newApp', () => App);

If Your project name is same as the name in the registerComponent than check in which project directory your running your app.

Or if that still not working for u than see the node of your project by running

> sudo apt lsof -i :(portnumber)8081

. Than kill the Process id(PID)
by running command

> kill -9  (PID)

This is because your process might run multiple instances Restart Your project.This might work for you!

Comment: Thank you, this problem is solved but it does not add any libraries. I've made a change in the question. Please ask me again and if you can help me

Comment: could you please tell me the exact functionality you want to achieve with that react-native-general-calenders

Comment: I want to show the calendar like any other component, and click on a new page every day of the week.

Comment: Cool as of my knowledge watchman is a deprecated package which no more exist with the npm .So the error which you getting has nothing to do with the watchman.The another thing is as you are dealing with calendar and i argue you to look at the **react-datepicker** and **moment** packages available with react and react-native.I belive that the error which your getting has nothing to do with the pckages.Hope this may help you!!